# PHP: Rendering included files in ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following files

```
 /includes
     - file_inc1.php
     - file_inc2.php
 ajax.php
 index.php
```

index.php calls an ajax request to ajax.php and ajax.php has something like below code

```
$nextStep = $_GET["nextStep"];
if($nextStep == 1) {
  include "includes/file_inc1.php";
} else if($nextStep == 2) {
  include "includes/file_inc2.php";
}
```

With this set-up, does anyone have a clue why the returned response from ajax is empty?

Comment: apparently it is not 1 nor 2, or the php files don't echo out anything.

Comment: Hi n-dru, my ajax call passes a get variable something like ajax.php?nextStep=1, so the file should be able to include the necessary files

Comment: Well then, The includes aren't echoing anything. Can we see the contents of both includes

Comment: Hi Platinum Industries, the contents of the files is something like   ----  `<div class="row fadeInUp text-center" id="map-locator">Hello<?php // Some mysql and php codes here ?></div>`

Comment: John, can you post the contents of the other files and the code you use to make that ajax call please?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the Ajax request is going to the URL (including the query string) that you think it is? How are you checking what the response is?

Answer (score 1):

```
$nextStep = $_GET["nextStep"];
if($nextStep == '1') {
  include "includes/file_inc1.php";
} else if($nextStep == '2') {
  include "includes/file_inc2.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses. I was able to solve my own problem. I need to make sure that on my includes/file_inc1.php and includes/file_inc2.php files, I use ob_start() and ob_get_clean() like so:

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   // HTML + MYSQL + OTHERS
   echo ob_get_clean();
?>
```